# Convert string with spaced out numbers into array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm working in Python and currently I have a list which looks like

```
['001   2.4600       0.46  2.36E+003   86.66  16.77       0.33  1.32E+003   74.41  17.61       0.40  2.21E+003   87.39  22.07',
 '002   10.310       0.38  2.95E+002   76.88   4.53       0000  000000000   00000   0000       0.34  2.62E+002   97.36   4.41',
 '003   74.840       0.63  5.07E+002   64.63   4.03       0.57  4.15E+002   61.96   3.99       0.63  5.43E+002   64.67   5.16',
...
```

and so on, with quite a few more elements. Each element of the list is a string, containing various figures which have spaces between them. i.e, as above, the first element has 001, 2.4600, 0.46 and so on.

The point is that I want to turn each element of the list into a row of an array. The aim is to have a large array giving me all the information which is currently just numbers separated by spaces inside strings in a list.

I'm sure I can use the built in array module to do this but I just can't figure out how.

Any ideas? Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using the `array` module is probably bogus, as an `array.array` object [is, essentially, a `list` with constrained data type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array). You cannot use vectorized operations on them. Further, an `array.array` is a 1D object.

That said, you possibly want to use the [`numpy` module](http://www.numpy.org/), whose `array` object is a multidimensional array on which you can operate at your will.

```
# idiomatic manner of importing numpy
import numpy as np

data = ['1 2 3.', '4. 5 8']
arraydata = np.array([[float(n) for n in row.split()] for row in data])
print arraydata

# [[ 1.  2.  3.]
#  [ 4.  5.  8.]]
```

Comment: This appears to have worked beautifully. The only slight quibble is that when I do the equivalent of "print arraydata" it prints 2 separate array (which I want) but both with 4 rows and 4 columns, rather than 1 row and 14 columns.

Comment: I guess you are mistaking the way the array is printed (with 4 numbers per row) with the internal representation of the data (which is organized in rows of 14 elements).  You can check what I mean by  printing individual entries of your array, like `print arraydata[1,11]` that gives you `260.0`, i.e., the 12th element in the 2nd row (remember, Python counts starting from zero, and the 1st element  while addressing a 2D array is the row count).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want floats in the final list of lists, try this:

```
>>> data = ['001 2.4600 0.46 2.36E+003 86.66 16.77 0.33 1.32E+003 74.41 17.61 0.40 2.21E+003 87.39 22.07', '002 10.310 0.38 2.95E+002 76.88 4.53 0000 000000000 00000 0000 0.34 2.62E+002 97.36 4.41', '003 74.840 0.63 5.07E+002 64.63 4.03 0.57 4.15E+002 61.96 3.99 0.63 5.43E+002 64.67 5.16']

>>> [list(map(float, row.split())) for row in data]
[[1.0, 2.46, 0.46, 2360.0, 86.66, 16.77, 0.33, 1320.0, 74.41, 17.61, 0.4, 2210.0, 87.39, 22.07], [2.0, 10.31, 0.38, 295.0, 76.88, 4.53, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.34, 262.0, 97.36, 4.41], [3.0, 74.84, 0.63, 507.0, 64.63, 4.03, 0.57, 415.0, 61.96, 3.99, 0.63, 543.0, 64.67, 5.16]]
```

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) just says 'do this function (`float()`) on everything in this list (the result of `split()`, which is a list of strings)'. In Python 3 it returns an iterator, so we have to ask for the `list()` of it. It's often better to use a for loop or list comprehension instead of map, but in this case it's handy.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understood correctly

```
res = []
for row in my_list:
    res.append(list(map(float, row.split())))
```

Here you will have a matrix of values, in string format. Added conversion

Comment: I don't think `split(' ')` would work. Looks like OP's strings have either multiple spaces, or tabs instead of spaces. Instead, just use `split()` to split at any whitespace characters. Also, you could make this a list comprehension: `res = [x.split() for x in lst]`

Comment: Agree, I will modify it

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your data is stored in a list called data you could use
`data =[[int(el) for el in string.split(' ')] for string in data]`

Comment: Do those look like integers? Also, better use `split()` instead of `split(' ')`